# Why is this program valid? I was trying to create a syntax error

Tags: perl

I'm running ActiveState's 32 bit [ActivePerl](https://www.activestate.com/activeperl) 5.14.2 on Windows 7. I wanted to mess around with a Git pre-commit hook to detect programs being checked in with syntax errors. (Somehow I just managed to do such a bad commit.) So as a test program I randomly jotted this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

Syntax error!

exit 0;
```

However, it compiles and executes with no warnings, and errorlevel is zero on exit. How is this valid syntax?

Comment: Did you just prove that typing random words into perl produces working programs??!?!?!?!

Comment: @PeterM Hardly random words.  I proved I don't know enough about Perl syntax.  Now I know a bit more.

Comment: You probably want `no indirect` to stop those ones from happening

Comment: This is the **most famous** perl question ever. Even better as [Schwartz's snippet](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=663393): `whatever  / 25 ; # / ; die "this dies!";`

Comment: Written by linguist Larry Wall, Perl allows authors a lot of creative space. There is a sub-category in perl programming called Perl Poetry, valid Perl expressing stuff beyond computer interpretation: https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1111395

Answer (score 573, accepted):

Perl has a syntax called "indirect method notation". It allows

```
Foo->new($bar)
```

to be written as

```
new Foo $bar
```

So that means

```
Syntax error ! exit 0;
```

is the same as

```
error->Syntax(! exit 0);
```

or

```
error->Syntax(!exit(0));
```

Not only is it valid syntax, it doesn't result in a run-time error because the first thing executed is `exit(0)`.

---

This feature can be disabled using any of the following:

```perl
no feature qw( indirect );  # Perl 5.32+

use v5.36;                  # Perl 5.36+

no indirect;                # CPAN module
```

Comment: Good explanation! But shouldn't the not operator (`!`) cause a syntax error?

Comment: @Hassan, Why? It's followed by an expression.

Comment: Okay, maybe because I don't know perl, but in many other languages, that would only work if `exit`'s return value is a boolean (or something else that can be the operand of `!`), ie simply being an expression is not enough.

Comment: I got as far as reading it as "Syntax error !exit 0;", but I didn't think about indirect invocation.  Spent a lot of time forgetting that!

Comment: @Hassan, When `exit` returns (never), it does return a boolean, just like every single other op and sub in scalar context. That's wouldn't be a syntax error anyway, that would be a type error.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Again, I'm pretty perl-ignorant, so sorry about that.

Comment: @Hassan, Think of it this way, `!exit(0)` can no more be a type error than `!$x` since neither are typed.

Comment: Non-typed languages give me the jitters.

Comment: @Hassan, The language has types. Specifically, values have types. Operators and subs are simply not confined to returning specific types of values. This turns out to be *very* useful at little cost (thanks to warnings).

Comment: @Nawaz, It's actually quite popular. It's used by everyone that constructs objects in Java and C++, and a large body of Perl programmers that uses `new Class` and `print $fh ...` instead of `Class->new(...)` and `$fh->print(...)`. I will grant you that it causes a weird error messages, though

Answer (score 118):

I don't know why, but this is what Perl makes of it:

```
perl -MO=Deparse -w yuck
BEGIN { $^W = 1; }
use warnings;
use strict 'refs';
'error'->Syntax(!exit(0));
yuck syntax OK
```

It seems that the parser thinks you're calling the method `Syntax` on the `error`-object... Strange indeed!

Comment: That's indirect method call syntax. It's (sort of) working here because the `exit(0)` is evaluated first, making the program exit before it tries to pass the result to `'error'->Syntax()`.

Comment: Perl seems to assume the "indirect (object) syntax", usually used like `new Class` instead of `Class->new()`. To call the method `Syntax`, the `exit` function is executed, so the run-time error never occures.

Comment: Congratulations. You found a program where you need to add a semi-colon in order do get the compile to fail.

Comment: `use strict;
use warnings;

error->Syntax(! print "hi");` 
Yields: Syntax Ok on perl -MO=Deparse as well, but with `use warnings` it should probably say something since it can figure out that its not being loaded. Instead it throws a runtime error "Can't locate object method .. ".

Answer (score 57):

The reason you do not get an error is that the first executed code is

```
exit(0);
```

Because you did not have a semicolon on the first line:

```
Syntax error!
```

The compiler will guess (incorrectly) that this is a subroutine call with a `not` operator `!` thrown in. It will then execute the arguments to this subroutine, which happens to be `exit(0)`, at which point the program exits and sets errorlevel to 0. Nothing else is executed, so no more runtime errors are reported.

You will notice that if you change `exit(0)` to something like `print "Hello world!"` you do get an error:

```
Can't locate object method "Syntax" via package "error" ...
```

and your error level will be set:

```
> echo %errorlevel%
255
```

Comment: `>The compiler will guess (incorrectly)`

The compiler can't do anything incorrectly.

Comment: @LiamLaverty Yes, it can. It can guess incorrectly what the human meant.

Comment: The human is the incorrect one in the equation. The compiler can only be "correct" or "broken". It doesn't get an opinion on the definition of the language or a user's intention.

Comment: @LiamLaverty It would be a pretty neat compiler if it could guess the user's intention in this case, yes. Hence, the compiler cannot guess correctly. You might be doing some technical jargon analysis of my statement, which is, I might add, the incorrect way to read it.

Comment: Isn't it an interpretater? ;-)

Comment: @Rikki Possibly an interpreter. :P

Answer (score 35):

As noted above this is caused by the indirect method calling notation.  You can warn on this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
no indirect;

Syntax error!

exit 0;
```

Produces:

```
Indirect call of method "Syntax" on object "error" at - line 5.
```

This requires the [indirect CPAN module](http://metacpan.org/module/indirect).

You can also use `no indirect "fatal";` to cause the program to die (this is what I do)

Comment: From Perl 5.32 onwards you can disable indirect feature and you longer need to add a CPAN module:
`use v.5:32; no feature 'indirect';`

Answer (score 6):

Try [Perl 6](https://perl6.org/), it seems to fulfill your expectations more readily:

```
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling synerror.p6
Negation metaoperator not followed by valid infix
at synerror.p6:1
------> Syntax error!⏏<EOL>
    expecting any of:
        infix
        infix stopper
```

Answer (score 3):

> In this [paper](https://famicol.in/sigbovik/), we aim to answer a long-standing open problem in the
>   programming languages community: is it possible to smear paint on the
>   wall without creating valid Perl?

TLDR; Hardly