# Why is this program valid?

Tags: php

Reading [this fascinating question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11695110/why-is-this-program-valid-i-was-trying-to-create-a-syntax-error) made me remember a code snippet I stumbled across a few weeks ago; it gave me quite a few minutes of confusion until I figured out why it works, maybe it will be interesting for others as well.

```
<?php

http://example.com/some-article
$items = get_items();
// etc.
```

Obviously the programmer wanted to add an explanatory link as a comment before the code block, but forgot to add the `//` to the beginning. Nevertheless, the code works fine. Can you tell why?

Comment: I guess the code colorer helps a lot with the answer :).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `http:` is a [goto](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php) label, and the rest of the line is commented out.

Comment: and you sir, type faster than me LOL

Comment: Well, it is not really converted into anything, it IS a goto label :).

Comment: Heheh... this question was a bonus on the final exam for one of my classes at my university. I felt so stupid when the lecturer gave us the answer to that one. xD

And very true, bažmegakapa.

Comment: @BrandonJ.Dusseau Just edited the answer so I could upvote it ;).