# How can I make Perl6 (MoarVM / Rakudo) warn about all missing semicolons?

Tags: raku

In Perl 5, it's best to use

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
```

to ask the compiler to complain about missing semicolons, undeclared variables, etc.

I have been informed by citizens of the Perl community here on SO that Perl 6 `use`s `strict` by default, and this seems after testing to be the case.

[Semicolons aren't required for the last statement in a block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16458231/4532996), but if I extend the block later, I'll be chagrinned when my code doesn't work because it's the same block (and also I want semicolons everywhere because it's, like, consistent and stuff).

My assumption is that Perl 6 doesn't even *look* at semicolons for the last statement in a block, but I'm still curious: is there a way to make it stricter yet?

Comment: I don't think Perl 5 warns about missing semicolons at the end of a block either, at least not with just `use strict` and `use warnings`.

Comment: You could create a slang that requires it.

Comment: "if I extend the block later, I'll be chagrinned when my code doesn't work ...". It almost certainly won't even compile if you omit the semi-colon. Perls embed a syntactic analog to [self-clocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-clocking_signal) in their grammar. You get a compile time error ("Two terms in a row across lines (missing semicolon or comma?)"), accurately pinpointing the exact location of the problem, if you accidentally omit a semi-colon, in almost all cases. This is the main reason why having semi-colon separation of statements is better than not having them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than enforce the extra semi-colon, Rakudo does try to give you a good error/hint if you do add to your block and forget to separate statements.

Typically I get "Two terms in a row across lines (missing semicolon or comma?)" when this happens.