# How to create instance in perl if we dont have new() named constructor

Tags: perl

i was thinking about new() constructor. As we know that we can give any name. Generally we do like this..

```
package PP;
sub new
{
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = {
        _first => shift,
        _last  => shift,
        _st       => shift,
    };

    print "First Name is $self->{_first}\n";
    print "Last Name is $self->{_last}\n";
    print "ST is $self->{_st}\n";
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}
```

and at the time of calling we do as below:

```
$object = new PP( "Mohan", "Sohan", 223345);
```

So here we are using `new` because we have constructor name `'new()'` but how we will handle that if constructor name is few() (instead of new()). is that like below?

```
$object = few PP( "Mohan", "Sohan", 223345);
```

Comment: The easiest way to answer this question is try it out and see if it works

Comment: Your question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11695110/133939

Comment: i saw that post but no where related to this.

Comment: The question may not be similar, but the accepted answer there is applicable to your query. It explains 'indirect method notation', which is what you are asking about.

Comment: [`perlobj #Indirect Object Syntax`](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.12.3/perlobj.html#Indirect-Object-Syntax)

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing special about `new`. (`bless` is what really constructs the object.) So

```
$object = few PP( "Mohan", "Sohan", 223345);
```

is the equivalent of

```
$object = new PP( "Mohan", "Sohan", 223345);
```

Indirect method calls can cause confusing errors, so the following is usually recommended

```
$object = PP->new( "Mohan", "Sohan", 223345);

$object = PP->few( "Mohan", "Sohan", 223345);
```

Comment: @user3518094 You can mark this answer as Accepted by clicking on the tick-mark on the left side.