# simple factorial function in perl error: return outside a subroutine

Tags: perl

I am working on a factorial function in Perl.
The code below gives me the error `Can't return outside a subroutine.`

```
factorial {
    my $n = $ARGV[0];
    if( $n <= 1 ){
        return 1;  # ----- Error Here -----
    }
    else {
        return $n * factorial($n - 1);
    }
}
```

I believe my if statement is still inside the subroutine. What is causing the error?

Comment: You define a subroutine by `sub factorial { ... }`.  Without the `sub` keyword  it's something else, and not a subroutine

Comment: Call function in the main `factorial();`

Comment: Also note, that `$ARGV[0]` is the first command line argument to your program, not the first parameter to your subroutine (that's in `$_[0]`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indirect method notation strikes again!<sup>[1]</sup>

```
factorial { ... }
```

is being parsed as

```
(do { ... })->factorial
```

The problem is that you are missing the `sub` keyword at the start of the sub's declaration. Replace

```
factorial { ... }
```

with

```
sub factorial { ... }
```

---

Also, subroutine arguments are provided in `@_`, not `@ARGV`, so

```
my $n = $ARGV[0];
```

should be

```
my $n = $_[0];
  -or-
my $n = shift;
  -or-
my ($n) = @_;
```

---

Finally, using a recursive approach is very inefficient. Sub calls are rather expensive. The following is much faster:

```
sub factorial {
    my $n = shift;
    my $acc = 1;
    $acc *= $_ for 2..$n;
    return $acc;
}
```

---

1. It's existence causes many errors from being caught when they should be, as you can see in [this magnificent example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11695110/589924).