# Why does "try" not cause an undefined subroutine error?

Tags: perl

A couple of times I've ran into the situation where I've forgotten to load the `Try::Tiny` module in my script and I've still used its `try-catch` block, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; 
use warnings;

try {
  call_a( 'x' );
} catch {
  die "ACTUALLY die $_";
};


sub call_a {
  die "Yes, I will";
}
```

For some reason, the script works fine without giving any hints that there is no `try`. No `Undefined subroutine` errors. This makes me wonder why my raised exceptions are not caught.

Why does this work silently, without an error?

**EDIT**

I looked into symbol table as well:

```
say "$_: %main::{ $_ }" for keys %main::;
```

and found there no `try`. Also I tried to call it as `main::try` in the script above, and it caused also no errors.

Comment: The code simply dies when evaluating arguments before the non-existing function `try` is called.

Comment: @nwellnhof So, as argument call for `try` (`call_a`) runs before call to `try` itself and dies during it, `try` is never tried. I tried `anything` instead of `try`, with same result. Your analysis seems correct. Submit it as an answer, please.

Comment: @nwellnhof Still, I made another version, when `call_a` randomly dies. And if it does die, `catch` block runs too. If `catch` dies too, then is still no errors. If `catch` does not `die`, we got error: `Can't locate object method "catch"`. It does not disprove your analysis, of course. It just illustrates, how you can cut yourself with this.

Comment: correction: 'And if it does not die'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is due to the indirect-object syntax, and is a more elaborate variation on [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11695310/4653379).

The ["indirect object notation"](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Invoking-Class-Methods) allows code

```
PackageName->method(@args);
```

to be written as

```
method PackageName @args;
```

So the "try" and "catch" words don't matter.  The interesting bit here is the more involved and extended syntax, with two parts, each in this indirect object notation.

The code in question in fact has `method BLOCK LIST` form, but that also goes by indirect object syntax into `(do BLOCK)->method(LIST)`, where `do BLOCK` needs to produce a name of a package or a blessed (object) reference for a meaningful method call.  This is seen below in `Deparse` output.

Using [B::Deparse](https://perldoc.perl.org/B/Deparse.html) compiler backend (via [O](https://perldoc.perl.org/O.html) module) on this code

```
use strict; 
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

try   { call_a( 'x' ) } 
catch { 
    die "ACTUALLY die";
    #say "NO DONT die";
};

sub call_a { 
    die "Yes it dies";
    #say "no die";
}
```

as `perl -MO=Deparse script.pl` should show a very close approximation of what runs:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
try {
    call_a('x')
} do {
    die 'ACTUALLY die'
}->catch;
sub call_a {
    use warnings;
    use strict;
    use feature 'say';
    die 'Yes it dies';
}
undef_sub.pl syntax OK
```

The nested indirect object syntax is apparently too much for `Deparse` which still leaves `method BLOCK LIST` form in the output. The equivalent code can be spelled out as

```
(do { call_a('x') })->try( (do { die("ACTUALLY die") })->catch() );
```

what in this case is more simply

```
call_a('x')->try( die("ACTUALLY die")->catch() );
```

Thus the original code is interpreted as valid syntax (!) and it is the *contents of the block after `try` (`call_a('x')`) that runs first* --- so the program dies and never gets to go for the "method" `try`.

It gets more interesting if we change the example to

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

try   { call_a( 'x' ) }
catch {
    #die "ACTUALLY die"; 
    say "NO DONT die";
};

sub call_a {
    #die "Yes it dies";
    say "no die";
}
```

with no `die`-ing  anywhere. Run it with `-MO=Deparse` to see

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
try {
    call_a('x')
} (catch {
    say 'NO DONT die'
} );
sub call_a {
    use warnings;
    use strict;
    use feature 'say';
    say 'no die';
}
undef_sub.pl syntax OK
```

which is now in a straight-up `method {} args` syntax (with `args` itself shown by `Deparse` in an indirect object notation as well). 
The equivalent code is

```
call_a('x')->try( say("NO DONT die")->catch() );
```

where first the `call_a()` goes and, after it returns, then the code for the argument list in the `try` method call runs next. We aren't running into a `die` and an actual run goes as

```
no die
NO DONT die
Can't call method "catch" without a package or object reference at ...
```

So now a problem with the *method "catch"* does come up.

Thanks to [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) for comments

---

If the block above *were to* return a name of a package (or object reference) which does have a method `catch` then the `try` would finally be attempted as well

```
use strict; 
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

BEGIN {
    package Catch;
    sub catch { say "In ", (caller(0))[3] };
    $INC{"Catch.pm"} = 1;
};

use Catch;

try   { call_a( 'x' ) } 
catch { 
    say "NO DONT die";
    "Catch";
};

sub call_a { say "no die" }
```

Now we have the equivalent

```
call_a('x')->try( do { say("NO DONT die"); 'Catch' }->catch() );
```

with the output

```
no die
NO DONT die
In Catch::catch
Can't call method "try" without a package or object reference at undef_sub.pl line 14.
```

Comment: You mention `METHODNAME PKGNAME LIST`, but the code uses `METHODNAME BLOCK LIST`. You might want the clarify that the latter is equivalent to `(do BLOCK)->METHODNAME(LIST)`. You see this for `catch` in the Deparse, but Deprase continued to use the indirect notation for `try`.

Comment: In fact, because Deparse still uses an indirect method call, I'd avoid using it in the answer at all. [Suggested edit](https://pastebin.com/bRGZ8ymn)

Comment: @ikegami Edited, thank you.  Probably (way) too long/wordy but at least should be clear now

Comment: @zdim Thank you for such thorough explanation!

Comment: @w.k  You are welcome and thanks for saying that :)  Let me know if more/better is needed