# Skip a get request in perl if it takes more than a specified time

Tags: perl, curl, timeout

I am writing a perl script to extract certain data using curl commands.
EG:

```perl
my $raw_json = `curl -X GET <some website url> -H <some parameters>`;
```

The issue is sometimes this website crashes and my code gets stuck at the same place for a long time. I want the code to skip this line and go to the next line if the request is taking more than a specified time, say 30 seconds.

I tried using $SIG{ALRM} in my script as follows:

```
my $timeout = 30;
eval {
   local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "alarm\n" }; # NB: \n required
   alarm $timeout;
   my $raw_json = `curl -X GET <some website url> -H <some parameters>`;
   alarm 0;
};
if ($@) {
 print "\nERROR!\n";
   die;   # propagate unexpected errors
      # timed out
} 
else {
   # didn't
}
```

I expected the run to stop after 30 seconds, but what is happening is I do get the "ERROR" statement printed after 30 seconds but get request keeps on running even after that.

Comment: Very related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94604/does-curl-have-a-timeout TL;DR Use the curl options `--connect-timeout` and `--max-time`.

Comment: Whenever you are using a system call to do something, know that it most often is a shortcut. Sometimes you run into issues with your shortcut, and you start problem solving and realize it is no longer a shortcut. That is what is happening here. You should look for a perl library to do the job for you. I googled and found [`WWW::Curl`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Curl), for example, but I don't know if it is a good one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `curl` is happening in a subprocess, so you need to stop that subprocess. Perl isn't going to stop that for you.

Use the `--connect-timeout` or `--max-time` to `curl` so you don't need the alarm and `curl` cleans itself up.

As @ikegami suggested, the next simplest thing is [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run), which can handle the details of a timeout for an external process.

Or, if you want to handle the alarm yourself, you need to work at a lower level so you have the PID of the subprocess and can kill it yourself. See [perlipc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc).

Comment: To avoid going to a lower lever, you could switch to IPC::Run which supports timeouts. The first idea sounds best, though.

Answer (score 3):

Best to set `curl`'s own timer, and can do that using Perl's `libcurl` wrapper, [Net::Curl::Easy](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Curl::Easy)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Net::Curl::Easy qw(:constants); 

my $curl = Net::Curl::Easy->new; 
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_URL, "www.example.com" );  
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); 

$curl->perform;
```

See constants in [curlopt_easy_setopt](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html), or the straight-up list in [easy_setopt_options](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/easy_setopt_options.html).  Here I use
[CURLOPT_TIMEOUT](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_TIMEOUT.html), for the whole operation, while there is
[CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT.html) to consider as well. There are yet other timeouts.

This module uses C-style interface but then again this will be familiar to `curl`'s use.

---

A more realistic use, with a returned document stored in a variable and `perform` checked for errors (most methods [throw on errors](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Curl::Easy#Net::Curl::Easy::Code))

```
my $curl = Net::Curl::Easy->new; 
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_URL, "www.example.com" );  
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, \my $response);  # or declare earlier
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); 

eval { $curl->perform };
if ($@ and ref $@ eq "Net::Curl::Easy::Code" ) {
    die "curl eval-ed: $@";
}
elsif ($@) { die $@ }  # probably not curl error, re-raise

say $response;
```

In newer Perls we have nicer exception handling ways, of [try-catch](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn#Try-Catch-Exception-Handling) style. See for example [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71231483/4653379) for an example and links.

Answer (score 1):

Other approach may be with [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent) module, so you have a higher control on what is happening with your request, define timeouts, and all you need to send a request and analyze the response.

[HTTP::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Tiny) is an alternative designed for doing simple requests. In both cases, module installation is required, but it's an easy task.