# Is lowercase "begin" a Perl keyword?

Tags: perl, keyword

I'm running Perl scripts version 5.28 under Linux Debian with some experimental "extensions" and got an strange behavior. In a mixed Pascal-SQL-Perl programming session, I miss typed a lowercase `begin` instead of an `else` in an if-else-statement (see test code below) and got an valid but malfunctioning code.

I'm aware that the uppercase `BEGIN` keyword belongs to `BEGIN, UNITCHECK, CHECK, INIT and END` program "pre- and post-program-running" group. But I used the lowercase `begin` variant and I got a valid running code. It seems to me, that the `begin {...}` block is executed separately after the `if (...) {...}` expression, which causes an unwanted early return.

Has the lowercase `begin` any meaning in a Perl case sensitive programming context?

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use v5.20;
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(signatures);
no warnings 'once';
no warnings 'experimental';
no warnings 'experimental::signatures';

&if_exotic(1000);
&if_normal(1000);

# --------------------------------------
# Bad variant
# --------------------------------------
sub if_exotic($want) {

   if ($want>0) {
       print "BAD: ..running $want operations\n";
   } begin {
       print "BAD: ..nothing to do\n";
       return;
   }

    print "Do something $want times\n";
   
}

# --------------------------------------
# Good variant
# --------------------------------------
sub if_normal($want) {

   if ($want>0) {
       print "GOOD: ..running $want operations\n";
   } else {
       print "GOOD: ..nothing to do\n";
       return;
   }

    print "Do something $want times\n";
}
```

```
/usr/bin/perl "test-if-begin"
BAD: ..running 1000 operations
BAD: ..nothing to do
GOOD: ..running 1000 operations
Do something 1000 times
```

Comment: Related: [Why is this program valid? I was trying to create a syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11695110/589924)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is Perl's [indirect object notation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj#Indirect-Object-Syntax) in action.

It allows the (recommended) syntax

```
PackageName->method(args-list)
```

to be written as (a "*discouraged*")

```
method PackageName arg-list
```

Let's boil down the example program to

```
use warnings;
use strict;

indirect_notation_gotcha();

print "all good?\n";

sub indirect_notation_gotcha {

    anyword {
        print "This body stands for package name\n";
        return;                                      # runs before "anyword"
    }

}
```

By the indirect-object syntax the code inside the sub is equivalent to

```
do {
    print "This body stands for package name\n";
    return
} -> anyword;
```

This is legal syntax and at runtime the `return` statement is what "saves" it as it never gets to the non-existent `anyword`.

If we drop the `return`

```
indirect_notation_gotcha();

print "all good?\n";

sub indirect_notation_gotcha {
    anyword {
        print "This body stands for package name\n";
    }
}
```

Now the `anyword` *is* attempted and we get

```
This body stands for package name
Can't locate object method "anyword" via package "1" (perhaps you forgot to load "1"?) at ...
```

---

- Directly related

  [Why is this program valid? I was trying to create a syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11695110/why-is-this-program-valid-i-was-trying-to-create-a-syntax-error)
- Also directly related, more complex and with a twist

  [Why does "try" not cause an undefined subroutine error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57989765/why-does-try-not-cause-an-undefined-subroutine-error/57997918#57997918)
- In many cases one can see what the interpreter does with the code given to it by using [O](https://perldoc.perl.org/O) with `Deparse` backend, like

  ```
  perl -MO=Deparse script.pl
  ```

  However, with more complex code this may not work, like in the second example above

As shown in the link on top, in newer Perls this is a feature that can be disabled (with [v5.32+](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.32.0/perldelta#Updated-Modules-and-Pragmata))

```
 no feature qw(indirect);  # v5.32+
```

In yet newer Perls it gets disabled in the bundle as well

```
use v5.36;
```

See [perldelta for 5.36.0](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.36.0/perldelta#use-v5.36).

Comment: One way to see this is by deparsing the script: `perl -MO=Deparse test.pl`